# flutter pub add google_sign_in finished with exit code 65

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add google sign in package to my product and get this Error:
What can i do ?

flutter pub add google_sign_in

***Because google_sign_in depends on google_sign_in, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65***

flutter doctor: stable, 3.3.10 • No issues found!

I also swich to the flutter beta channel but get the same error.

I also get a simular Error if i want to add firebase_auth.
Firebase Core added correctly!

I want to add this package to my dependencies.

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: google_sign_in
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Add your pubspec.yaml file here

Comment: Added my pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project name is the same as the package google_sign_in, it might be a problem. because in your pubspac.yaml your project name is google_sign_in.